# Visual Studio Code does not give suggestions or autocompletion when creating a new file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have this problem, I have all dependencies and plugin installed to work with java spring.

**Plugins installed:**
Extension Pack for Java
sonarlint
Spring Boot Extension Pack

**Operating system: Ubuntu**
jdk version: 17LTS

This did not happen to me before, now I have to close and reopen Visual Studio Code to get the suggestions. like in this giff [image](https://res.cloudinary.com/bayyand/image/upload/v1688960874/2023-07-09_22-37-42_zd7c1j.gif)

I tried to close and reopen the code editor and then it works correctly, but it is annoying every time I create a new file to close and reopen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Related guthub link: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191

Answer (score -1):

`this issue has been fixed in the latest vscode@1.80.1 version.` according to replies from [GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191#issuecomment-1635181642).

Comment: please don't answer duplicate questions. vote to close as duplicate

Comment: you've now not only answered a dup of the canonical question, but answered _another_ dup that you already answered. this is not how this platform is supposed to work. I counted three. are you going to do more?